# Selenium - Select co-ordinates of image

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I have an image in which I can click on an area & it crop the image from the center of your click.

I.e you click the middle of the image it will crop from that point.

I was wondering if there was anything in Selenium (Java) where you can click at specific co-ordinates of an image.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the mouse and click with Actions, given you have a element to offset from. You cannot click outside the browser content window or control Operating System elements.

```
moveToElement(WebElement toElement, int xOffset, int yOffset)
Moves the mouse to an offset from the top-left corner of the element.
```

The code (Java) would look like this:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
builder.moveToElement(knownElement, 10, 25).click().build().perform();
```